# Problem with getting a clear and smooth glass surface

Tags: cycles-render-engine, subdivision-surface, glass

Dear Blender Community,

right now I am trying to make a transparent glass shape with objects inside.
I tried to smooth the shape via subdivison and smooth modifiers.

With the subdivision the glass has a nice clear look but i get a lot of hard edges
[image]

Without it appears smoother but unfortunately it is appears less clear

[image]

Do you have an idea how I can get a smooth an clean look for the shape.
Thank you :)

[image: topology without subdivision]
topology without subdivision

[image: topology of the model with applied subdivision results in having bulky edges]

topology of the model with applied subdivision results in having bulky edges

Comment: Did you smooth shade it after using the subdivision surface modifier? - (in object mode with the object selected) `right-click > Shade Smooth` (not the same as the "smooth" modifier).

Comment: yes I did. A collegue told me the edges after the subdivision are a result of my mesh being to complex.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to tell without seeing your underlying topology (mesh in edit mode), but edges that are close together will form "creases" and any kind of bevel will mitigate the "roundness" of edges. It might be helpful if you could post a pic of your topology as well, to better understand what's really going on. If you're really stuck you might also consider posting your .blend file (or a minified example). You can do it here if you wish - https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hey Christopher, thanks for your reply. I Will add a photo of the topology to my post.

Comment: adding the actual blend file would be more helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

**A couple of changes to default settings**

The *Principled BSDF* shader has a default *Base Color* around .8, which means glass will be a little dark by default.  You can raise the base color to 1.0 for perfectly clear glass.

These dark spots -

[image]

are caused when the light reflects internally a number of times that exceeds the number of bounces allowed in render settings.

[image]

Usually it's the number of Glossy bounces which you can change here:

[image]

You can learn more listening to [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sv2wqwsvx-8&t=224s).

**To the model**

When modeling for subdivision it is often to your advantage to leave your mesh as low poly as possible, and let the interpolation algorithm do the work of placing the additional vertices with mathematical precision.  *Shade Smooth* will do the rest by interpolating the normals between the generated faces.

Observe the following model, and see how it is represented in edit mode.

[image]

(5 levels subdivision)

[image]

The glass tubes might be easier to construct using a curve.  This takes a lot of the work out of positioning.  I added a solidify modifier to this curve.

[image]

As a bonus, the curve may serve as a constraint for animation.

Comment: Thank you Allen for your help. So my model has to much geometry I guess. Is there any way to fix the model getting rid of the edges? Or do I have to rebuild everything?