Glass bottle shader issue
Why am I getting these dark spots? I have tried my best to remove them but failing miserably. Can a more experienced user lend some assistance? I have tried changing light paths, adding volume scatter and also have tried placing my scene in a cubebut nothing works 

hello could you please share your file?

If you turn up Total and Glossy bounces in Light Paths this should go away, unless it's a result of the environment the object is in.
I have several answers on glass that you may find helpful - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/222063/problem-with-getting-a-clear-and-smooth-glass-surface/222076#222076
